# $\frac{x^2y}{z}+\frac{y^2z}{x}+\frac{xz^2}{y}\geq x^2+y^2+z^2$

Tags: inequality, substitution, buffalo-way

Let $x,y,z$ be lengths of three sides of triangle. Show that $\frac{x^2y}{z}+\frac{y^2z}{x}+\frac{xz^2}{y}\geq x^2+y^2+z^2$. This seems simple but not easy. I try to use RAVI replacement but it doesn't work. 
I think it has a relation to the inequality $x^2y(x-y)+y^2z(y-z)+z^2x(z-x)$ ( which appears  in $IMO$ $1983$.). Give me some idea to solve this, thank you so much!

Comment: The inequality is not rotational. Are you sure the question is correct?

Comment: @HwChu oh i am sorry so much. I have already change my mistake.

Comment: I can write your inequality in SOS form but very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The hint.

Use the BW:

Let $x=a+u$, $y=a+v$ and $z=a+u+v$, where $a>0$, $u\geq0$ and $v\geq0.$

After this substitution you'll get something obvious.